# Which HL7-FHIR resource to use for an alarm button

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm trying to model a 'Social Care Alarm' service to see how it could map into the functionality of FHIR. A Social Care Alarm is basically an alarm button that a person wears at home, which when pressed (or when triggered by a fall sensor), sends a message to a central server where an operator calls the person who triggered the alarm.

The voice is obviously out of the scope, but could I do an 'alarm button', possibly also with geo-location? Would it be an Observation resource? The operator would typically have a web interface, with a list of triggered alarms. They'd then be able to clear the alarms, removing them from the list (but they'd be in the history).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a [Communication](http://hl7-fhir.github.io/communication.html) resource (from DSTU 2).  To clear it from the list, the user would update the Communication to note that it had been received.  The Communication would point to or contain the information to be conveyed, which could include geolocation.

Comment: When the operator receives a call, the operator must log the incomidng call and their respones to it. Would this log entry also be a communication resource? Possibly the same communication object as the incoming call alert? Or would one use an 'Encounter' for an incoming call to a social alarm service? These calls could be anything from social contact/loneliness, requesting help to go to the toilet, but also medical emergencies (though that's rarer).

Comment: Encounter would reflect the call.  Communication would reflect the information that's shared.